# Adding external libraries on CodeLite

Tags: external, libraries, codelite

I'm starting with CodeLite and I wonder how do I add an external library. I wanna make a SFML game using CodeLite and I'm getting some troubles with it. I used to program with QtCreator, but now I'm trying something new.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project icon on the left side (in the tree view) and select 'settings->common settings->linker'
There you have 2 fields:
Library paths and libraries, in the first one, place the path to your library and in the later, place the name of the library (you can omit the prefix and extension)

Eran

Comment: I tried this, I still get undefined reference errors

Comment: Sounds like you are having a compiler problems. Which compiler are you using? Showing the build log will help a lot (also, try posting this on the codelite's forum http://forums.codelite.org )

Comment: I'm using MinGW with gcc 4.8. I'll try there. Thank you.